# regex @something

Tags: regex

I want a regex to get in a text the `@something`, so I tried:

```
/@(\w+)/ig
```

this is @josh and @anne= @josh @anne match

the problem is, I want to ignore the ones with space after it, in the example above, ignore the @josh and just show @anne because @anne has no space after it and @josh has.

any ideas?

Comment: [`/@(\w+)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/iA9mH7/1)?

Comment: `\s` represents a whitespace character. Try `/@(/w+)[^\s]/ig`

Comment: What? In your example, both “@josh” and “@anne” have a space after the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
/@(\w+\b)(?! )/ig
```

The word boundary makes the match include 'entire words', the negative lookahead forbids the next character being a space.

The word boundary is necessary because without, it would match `@jos` inside `@josh and @anne`.

To make it match up to *any* whitespace character, use

```
/@(\w+\b)(?!\s)/ig
```

(where `\s` is 'any whitespace); to match up to any not-word character, you'd think it needs this

```
/@(\w+\b)(?!\w)/ig
```

but remember that the explicit `\b` already does that, so a plain

```
/@(\w+\b)/ig
```

is then enough.

Comment: Can I also stop if it is a \n or , or any special caracter like @ #?

Comment: @RickJoe: see my additions.